# Jquery add width to last th

Tags: jquery, css, width, fixed-header-tables

I am working on a fixed table header where I have a scrollbar. I am taking 2 tables one on top and other on bottom. Top table will have headers (Name, Address, Phone, Details), bottom table will have all rows with details. I have to add extra width 20px to last th to sync widths of both top table and bottom table. This might not be 20px but equal to scrollbar width. What I tried is any suggestion? My table is dynamically populated.

```
// Adding table width to sync with scrollbar
$(document).ready(function () {

    var thLastWidth = $('#fixedHeaderTable th:last').width()+18;
    $('#fixedHeaderTable th:last').css('width', thLastWidth + 'px');
});
```

Comment: If your table is dynamically populated, is it even populated by the time this runs? Or is this running before the table is populated?

Comment: I want this after table population. By default it gets 18px width dynamically. After loading I need to set it to 18px+20px;

Comment: How are you populating the table? Can we see that code?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var thLastWidth = function(i){
    i = $('#fixedHeaderTable th:last').width()+18;
    return i;
}
```